# Creating shortcut (button) for "Make this the only selectable layer" in Python 2.6?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python-2.6

I'm trying to create a script in Python 2.6 to make a button or a keyboard shortcut for "Make This The Only Selectable Layer". I came across the following VBA scripts on the net, but the problem is it's not working in ArcGIS 10. Can anyone help me with a Python script to do that?

```
Public Sub MakeLayerSelectable_Click()

  Dim pMxDocument As IMxDocument
  Dim pMap As IMap
  Dim pEnumLayer As IEnumLayer
  Dim pLayer As ILayer
  Dim pId As New UID
  Dim pFLayer As IFeatureLayer

  Set pMxDocument = Application.Document
  Set pMap = pMxDocument.FocusMap
  pId = "{6CA416B1-E160-11D2-9F4E-00C04F6BC78E}"
  Set pEnumLayer = pMap.Layers(pId, True)
  pEnumLayer.Reset
  Set pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next
  Do While Not pLayer Is Nothing
    If TypeOf pLayer Is IFeatureLayer Then
        Set pFLayer = pLayer
        pFLayer.Selectable = False
    End If
    Set pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next
  Loop

Set pLayer = pMxDocument.SelectedLayer

If TypeOf pLayer Is IFeatureLayer Then
  Set pFLayer = pLayer
    pFLayer.Selectable = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You're talking about replicating the functionality in right-click on layer in TOC > Selection > Make this layer the only selectable layer?

Comment: yes, exactly. TOC > Selection > Make this layer the only selectable layer

Answer (score 4):

**Use the customize option on your tools toolbar:**
[image]

---

---

**Search for the 'Make This Layer Only Selectable Layer' command, drag to toolbar.**
[image]

**This customization should be automatically saved to your 'Normal' template. AKA - it should work every time you open ArcMap.**

I found out about this the other day, you can put pretty much anything on your toolbar, I really like the *Export Map* and the *Page and Print Setup* functionality in the toolbar.

Comment: +1 for using the built-in application functionality before trying to write code to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the your reasonable answer. But I have to tell that I knew this before.

Comment: the problem is it gets inactive. It doesn't work.