# Assigning keyboard key to Python script in ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, shortcuts

I have a python script and I use it through my toolbox but I use it many times in a day.

Is it possible to assign a keyboard shortcut to my tool ?

Comment: I suppose he wants to get a keyboard shortcut for arctoolbox script. I suppose there is no way for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can [assign shortcuts](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00v00000000v000000) in ArcGIS by going to customize --> customize mode ---> commands and then keyboard to map to a specific key combination.

Also duplicate of this [question.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61925/how-to-change-add-keyboard-shortcuts-in-arcmap)

You could also try this method and have your script on your [toolbar](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19245/how-to-create-a-shortcut-a-button-for-make-this-the-only-selectable-layer-in) for easy access

Comment: As user30975 pointed out, Halil wanted to assign a shurtcut to a custom python script.

Comment: @Vladmir so you downvote when the >3 yr  thread is closed as a duplicate? To my knowledge, at the time this was posted you could not assign a short-cut to the keyboard, the only alternative being attaching it to a toolbar.