# Make this the only selectable layer (greyed out)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, select-by-location, tools, table-of-contents

Someone else has tried [Creating shortcut (button) for "Make this the only selectable layer" in Python 2.6?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19245/how-to-create-a-shortcut-a-button-for-make-this-the-only-selectable-layer-in) but, as pointed out there, the answer doesn't work.

When adding "Make this the only selectable layer" to the ArcGIS 10.3 menu, using the Customize tool, it adds the button to the main screen, but it is permanently greyed out.

Doing it the old-fashioned way (Table of Contents -> Layer -> Selection -> Make this the only selectable layer) works just fine, but it is a bit slow.

Has anyone had/resolved this problem?

Comment: Is this the command that appears when you right click on the layer? If so, you cannot add context menu items to a tool bar since they will always be greyed out.

Comment: Thanks @kenbuja for your answer. Wasn't aware of the difference between context menu items and other ones - it sounds like that's the issue. I'll give up on this one then!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue you are running into is simply that it behave similar to other ArcGIS tools in that it is dynamically responsive to the users actions. You must have a selection for that quick tool that you just added through customization to work. It should become available when you select at least one feature/row from a particular dataset.

Comment: Thanks @whyzar for your answer. I've tried what you suggest but it still remains greyed out. No worries, I'll just carry on as I was - just thought I might be missing something.